# Missing TrueCrypt volumes after moving files from a Mac to another

Tags: macos, truecrypt

I copied ALL the files from my old Macbook to my new iMac, including TrueCrypt.app (I don't have that Macbook anymore)

I was excepting that I could see the volumes I've created on TrueCrypt.app on the New iMac after copying the TrueCrypt.app from the Old Macbook.

Apparently I was wrong..

Can I/How can I see those volumes on the iMac ?

Help will be Most Appreciated.

Comment: Are the TrueCrypt volumes the only thing that seems not to have copied correctly?

Comment: Did you copy the TrueCrypt volumes to the same place on your new computer?